# Cooking schnitzel without thinning it

Tags: meat, frying, frying-pan, breadcrumbs

I'm quite good in cooking [schnitzels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnitzel#Ukraine), but in the place where I live now there is no hammer to thin the meat. I wander if I can use the same technique like coating in breadcrumbs and frying on the pan but on the non-thinned slices of meat? As far as I understand, this also involves cooking on a lower heat for a longer time, so it will cook properly over all of its thickness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how thick the meat is. A common mistake people make when cooking steak is not warming the meat up to room temperature before frying - which means the centre is cold when out side is crisp. Bring your pork up room temperature (or warmer), then coat and fry it ~140C. This will work up to about 3/4cm thick, and will also give you golden bread crumbs on the outside :)

The oven route will also work but I suggest you spray the bread crumb coat with sunflower oil or clarified butter to give you a nice finish. If you just bake it the coating will be dry.

@ElendilTheTail right about the rolling pin and heavy based pan!

If you like snitzel [Flamenquines](http://www.ferdiesfoodlab.co.uk/2011/03/recipe-flamenquines-cordoban-rolls-w.html) are definitely worth a try, really good!!

Answer (score 5):

The problem you will have is cooking the meat without burning the breadcrumbs and/or the breadcrumbs absorbing lots of oil. You could get around this by baking the schnitzel rather than frying them.

However, you don't necessarily need a hammer to thin the meat - a heavy saucepan or rolling pin will do just as good a job.

Comment: Nothing more to add. That answer sums it up really nice.

Comment: I've also used a thick sturdy plate to pound the meat thinner and tenderize using the edge.